# Equivalent statement to SQL Server's SELECT INTO in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I am a newbie to oracle. I have a requirement where i have to insert the values of some table to a temporary table. For instance, In MSSQL I used to use the query something like below.

Note: There can be much more complicated select query result, inserted to the temp table. i.e, actualtable in the below example can be any complicated query. Here i have just mentioned a simple example.

```
SELECT columna, columnb... INTO temptable FROM actualtable where columna=? and columnb=? and ..;
```

After the construction of above select query, i am doing data binding as well by preparing statement in Java.

In oracle I cannot do as above, I have to use as below

```
create table temptable as select columna, columnb... from actualtable where columna=? and columnb=? and ..;
```

After this I cannot do data binding. If I do, i get the exception - ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations. As its known I cannot do data binding for create table, create view etc.

What else can i do? I cannot create temp table before in hand. Because, i will not know the description of all the columns of temp table. Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a temporary table at all?

Comment: I agree with Frank: in Oracle you usually don't need temp tables the way you do in SQL Server (you could e.g. use a CTE instead)

Comment: I already have a temp table creation logic in the existing product framework. I have been asked to do data binding for it. For both oracle and MSSQL. For MSSQL, i achieved as mentioned above. But, with oracle i am stuck at the point, i mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two steps. First create the table with 0 rows by specifying a where condition that is always false:

```
CREATE TABLE temptable AS SELECT * FROM actualtable WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Then use `insert into .. select ...`, which is a DML statement, so you can use bind variables:

```
INSERT INTO temptable SELECT * FROM actualtable WHERE where columna=? and columnb=? and ..;
```

Comment: Thank you chris. I wrote a sample code. It worked!! I will try to integrate the same with the framework.